# Как создать карту офиса на Api 2 Yandex.Map?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Появилась потребность создать карту офиса в декартовых координатах с расположением мебели и офисной техники внутри. Подложкой должен являться скан чертежа офиса.
Если кто-то занимался подобным, поделитесь пожалуйста опытом, примерами.
Спасибо!

Comment: 1. Как вы себе это представляете (и какова цель)? 2. Вы уверены, что масштаба Яндекс.Карт для этого хватит?

Comment: Цель: документировать, использовать в работе и показывать сотрудникам что где находится. Нашел в сети такой пример, http://xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai/?p=475, представляю себе именно так, но не уверен что выбор с яндекс картами правильный, кроме этого примера больше ничего нет, и это настораживает. В первой версии API было подробное описание https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/map-custom-docpage, в текущей версии этого нет, возможно логичнее и надежнее использовать OpenLayers?

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время в документации актуальной версии API Яндекс.Карт есть [пример создания собственной карты](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map), с использованием своего [тайлового слоя](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Layer.html).

Сторонние же, более интересные решения на базе их API Яндекса можно найти в сети. Вот один неплохой, на мой взгляд, пример: [https://фестивальангарск.рф/skhema-trk/](https://xn--80aaafhivvfv9adje1a9k.xn--p1ai/skhema-trk/)

Comment: К сожалению яндекс карты не подходят из-за своей политики. Приложение НЕ в общем доступе, а цены заоблачные для небоьшой компании.

Comment: Вы правы, бесплатное использование инструментов Яндекса допустимо лишь при публичности итоговой карты. Если возможности разместить карту на общедоступной странице нет, или это недопустимо по иным соображениям (коммерческая или иная тайна), нужно искать сторонние решения.